# Can the HDD/SSD password on Toshiba Satellite laptops be reset?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, bios, passwords, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite laptop model 855D-S5320 from my sister-in-law that "mysteriously" has a BIOS and HDD/SSD password set on it. She knows the BIOS password, but doesn't know the HDD/SSD password.  I know about the "B500 jumper trick" to clear the BIOS password, but that doesn't seem to work on the HDD password.  This is a multi-part question then:

Is it possible to clear/reset the HDD/SSD password?  If so, how?

If it is not possible, can the HDD be reformatted in another laptop to clear the password?

If not, can the HDD be replaced to circumvent the password?  I've read that it might be a multi-part encryption system on the HDD and on the BIOS in non-volatile memory.